# Only getting 0 second video from First Order Motion Model

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm pretty new to this community and I can't figure out how to get the First Order Motion Model algorithm working. The only output I have had so far is just a video with a single frame. Here is the link to the website:
https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model

I'm attempting to use the VoxCeleb dataset pre-trained checkpoint, provided by github page above.

I'm running a windows laptop machine with an Intel i5-6200U and integrated graphics.

This is what I have entered into the command prompt:

`python run.py --config config/vox-256.yaml --mode animate --checkpoint checkpoint/vox-cpk.pth.tar`

This is the result:

```
C:\Users\caleb\Desktop\Python\Deepfake_files\first-order-model-master>python run.py --config config/vox-256.yaml --checkpoint checkpoint/vox-cpk.pth.tar --mode animate
Use random train-test split.
Animate...
0it [00:00, ?it/s]C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:2705: UserWarning: Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed to align_corners=False since 1.3.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of grid_sample for details.
  warnings.warn("Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed "
C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:2503: UserWarning: Default upsampling behavior when mode=bilinear is changed to align_corners=False since 0.4.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.
  warnings.warn("Default upsampling behavior when mode={} is changed "
C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:1351: UserWarning: nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead.")
1it [00:09,  9.26s/it]
```

The algorithm then outputs a video with only a single frame.

The input mp4 video is about 1 min long and both the driving video and source image are sized to 256x256

If anyone has any experience with this algorithm, please resond!

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because your input video is more than 30 seconds in length.

[This tutorial video](https://youtu.be/Q9Wo9AyrSqc) also describes that the input video must be less than 30 seconds long.